# How can i request a new api that was added in publisher-api.yaml

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I add a new api in the file below:

```
carbon-apimgt\components\apimgt\org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1\src\main\resources\publisher-api.yaml
```

Maven build success and generate some new files which are definded in the publisher-api.yaml.
I use postman to invoke this api but get a null response , why? How can i reuqest it?

Answer (score 0):

When you update the publisher-api.yaml with a new resource, you have to build two components.

1. carbon-apimgt/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1
2. carbon-apimgt/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.common

This will generate the required DTOs and interfaces for the implementation of the new resource.
Then you have to implement the logic behind the new resource. `carbon-apimgt/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/publisher/v1/impl` will now have a new java file and you can add the logic.